# simple algorithm on conditionals

Tags: php

My simple brain can't seem to put this together.

I want to do a check on some code to say:

```
if (($limit == 0) || ($count < $limit))
//do stuff
else
//exit
```

The values of limit are either 0, 1 or 4. Where 0 represents "unlimited" (don't ask).

So really what I want to say is

`if limit == 0 or count < limit (except when limit ==0)`

What is the best way to structure that?

Comment: What's not working? Can you be more specific? Are you getting an error message, or is the code just not behaving as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be helpful if you `var_dump` `$limit` and `$count` to make sure their types are correct. 
Your code is correct and when `$limit` is 0, it should evaluate to `TRUE` and the code should be run.

```
<?php
$limit = 0;
if ($limit == 0 || non_exisint_func()) {
  echo 'yeah';
}
```

http://3v4l.org/SH9mE - You will see that the second condition is not even evaluated.

Your condition will always pass if you put a `NULL`, `(bool) FALSE` or `(string) 0`.

Answer (score 2):

It is generally good practice to use brackets in conditional statements in Php.  Try this:

```
if (($limit == 0) or ($count < limit)) {
  //do something
} else {
  //do something else
}
```